# Loading artifacts from drools kie workbench for testing

Tags: drools-guvnor, kie

I am facing the following problem while testing a sample rule created by using workbench.

Model, rule and eclipse test scenario are attached.

[image]

---

[image]

Problem: getCity always return null

Equivalent model code as created in workbench.

The rule checks whether the customer id is less than 100. If the customer id is less than 100, then city is set to London.

```
package com.sample;
public class CustomerDetails implements java.io.Serializable
{

   static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private int customerID;
   private java.lang.String city;

   public CustomerDetails()
   {
   }

   public java.lang.String getCity()
   {
      return this.city;
   }

   public void setCity(java.lang.String city)
   {
      this.city = city;
   }

   public int getCustomerID()
   {
      return this.customerID;
   }

   public void setCustomerID(int customerID)
   {
      this.customerID = customerID;
   }

   public CustomerDetails(int customerID, java.lang.String city)
   {
      this.customerID = customerID;
      this.city = city;
   }

}
```

Code in eclipse used for testing

```
package com.sample;

import java.io.File;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.drools.compiler.kproject.ReleaseIdImpl;
import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.builder.KieScanner;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.kie.api.runtime.StatelessKieSession;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String url = "http://localhost:8080/kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.2.0.Final-jboss-as7/maven2/TestProject/demo/TestProject/1.0/TestProject-1.0.jar";
        ReleaseIdImpl releaseId = new ReleaseIdImpl("demo", "TestProject", "LATEST");
        KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
        kieServices.getResources().newUrlResource(url);
        KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(releaseId);
        KieScanner kieScanner = kieServices.newKieScanner(kieContainer);
        kieScanner.scanNow();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("kieContainer.getKieBaseNames() "+kieContainer.getKieBaseNames());

        KieSession newKieSession =kieContainer.newKieSession("session1");

       // StatelessKieSession kSession = kieContainer.newStatelessKieSession();
        CustomerDetails testdetails=new CustomerDetails();
        //BigInteger lcustomerID = BigInteger.valueOf(20);
        testdetails.setCustomerID(10);
        newKieSession.insert(testdetails);
        newKieSession.fireAllRules();
        //kSession.execute(testdetails);

        System.out.println("testdetails.getCustomerID()= " +testdetails.getCustomerID());
        System.out.println("City= " +testdetails.getCity());
       // while (true) {
            //runRule(kieContainer);
          //  System.out.println("Press enter in order to run the test again....");
          //  scanner.nextLine();
        //}


    }

}
```

Console output:

```
18:04:52.734 [main] DEBUG o.d.c.k.b.impl.KieRepositoryImpl - KieModule Lookup. ReleaseId demo:TestProject:1.0.1 was not in cache, checking classpath
18:04:52.739 [main] DEBUG o.d.c.k.b.impl.KieRepositoryImpl - KieModule Lookup. ReleaseId demo:TestProject:1.0.1 was not in cache, checking maven repository
18:04:52.776 [main] WARN  o.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenSettings - Environment variable M2_HOME is not set
18:04:55.172 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository
18:04:55.205 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository
18:04:56.527 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository
18:05:08.195 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultDependencyCollector - Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=3, ConflictMarker.markTime=1, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=2, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=2, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=11, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=1, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=340, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=62}
18:05:08.830 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository
18:05:08.835 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository
18:05:08.847 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultDependencyCollector - Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=0, ConflictMarker.markTime=1, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=0, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=0, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=0, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=1}
18:05:29.310 [main] INFO  o.d.c.k.b.impl.KieRepositoryImpl - KieModule was added: ZipKieModule[releaseId=demo:TestProject:1.0.1,file=C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository\demo\TestProject\1.0.1\TestProject-1.0.1.jar]
18:05:29.626 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository
18:05:29.628 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository
18:05:29.639 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository
18:05:29.927 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository
18:05:29.930 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository
18:05:29.947 [main] DEBUG o.e.a.i.i.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider - Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository
kieContainer.getKieBaseNames() [testsession1]
18:05:31.497 [main] DEBUG o.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl - Starting Engine in PHREAK mode
testdetails.getCustomerID()= 10
City= null
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you ask a specific question? It'll help others know what you are trying to do and what exactly you need resolved. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for responding. The question here is why is System.out.println("City= " +testdetails.getCity())  null when according to the rule it should be London.

Comment: Is there anything I am doing wrong in the class 'Testing'. As mentioned before, the rules are located in workbench and not as an eclipse project. I am loading the artifact(jar) via http.